# Find the number of permutations of $1,2,...,6$ with a special property

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of permutations of $1,2,...,6$ with the property that every number is mapped to a place whose difference from the original number is at most $2$. That is, if $f$ is the map, then for every $x \in \{1,2,...,6\}$ we have $|f(x)-x| \leq 2$. Does anyone have an elegant way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Let it be $A(6)$, or in general $A(n)$.
The number with $n$ in last place is clearly $A(n-1)$.
Let $B(n)$ be the number with $n-1$ in last place.
Let $C(n)$ be the number with $n-2$ in last place.
By considering where $n$ goes, get recursions for $A(n)$, $B(n)$ and $C(n)$ in terms of each other.
As a subset of $B(n)$  If n goes in place $n-1$ we are down to $A(n-2)$.  If the last three are n,n-2,n-1, it is $A(n-3)$.  If the last three are $n,n-3,n-1$ it is equivalent to $B(n-2)$.
I think $C(n)=B(n-1)+A(n-3)+A(n-4)$.

Comment: I do not see any obvious way to get the recursion for B and C. Can you put in a little more detail?